# Сколько сайтов по русскому есть на Stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, stackexchange

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, сколько сайтов по русскому есть на StackExchange? Я видел 3:

1. [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)
2. [Russian lanquage](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)
3. [Russian lanquage meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Между двумя последними есть разница?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сайтов на самом деле два:

- [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) это сайт на русском языке, посвященный русскому языку.
- [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) - англоязычный сайт о русском языке.

У каждого сайта сети StackExchange есть служебный раздел Мета (как, например этот, на котором вы задали вопрос) для обсуждения работы сайта, решения технических и организационных вопросов.

Таким образом, есть:

- [Русский язык *мета*](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/) - сайт поддержки для сообщества [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), и
- [Russian Language *meta*](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) - англоязычный сайт поддержки для англоязычного сообщества [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Тогда в чем разница между[Русский язык мета](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/) и этим сайтом, на котором я сейчас пишу?

Comment: @Серж Этот сайт - сайт поддержки ru.stackoverflow - сайта программистов (а не лингвистов).

Comment: Спасибо! Все стало ясно!